# how to join the tables and make this a single call to the database in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
public async Task<bool> UnSaveCourseAsync(int courseId, string userId)
        {
            this.logger.LogInformation($"Enter into service layer course id {courseId} and user id {userId}");

            var checkCourse = await this.lmsMasterRepository.GetExistsAsync<Playlist>(i => i.IsActive && !i.IsDeleted && i.Id == courseId).ConfigureAwait(false);
            var checkSavedBy = await this.lmsMasterRepository.GetExistsAsync<User>(q => q.IsActive && !q.IsDeleted && q.Id == userId).ConfigureAwait(false);
            bool courseresult = checkCourse ?? false;
            bool userresult = checkSavedBy ?? false;
            if (!courseresult)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Course is not Available");
            }

            if (!userresult)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("User is not Available");
            }

            var checkSavedCourse = await this.lmsMasterRepository.GetOneAsync<SavedCourse>(i => i.PlaylistId == courseId && i.SavedBy == userId && i.IsActive == true && i.IsDeleted == false).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (checkSavedCourse != null && checkSavedCourse.SavedBy == userId && checkSavedCourse.PlaylistId == courseId)
            {
                checkSavedCourse.IsDeleted = true;
                checkSavedCourse.IsActive = false;
                await this.lmsMasterRepository.UpdateAsync<SavedCourse>(checkSavedCourse).ConfigureAwait(false);
                return await this.lmsMasterRepository.SaveAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

for this method how to do database single call .

there are three tables one is playlist from this table we will get the course is present in table or not .
2nd table is user from which we will get the user is exist or not .and the 3rd table from which we will search that course and the user is present in saved Course table or not . then how can we do database single call.

first it will check in playlist table that course is present or not .
2nd in user table it will check the user s valid or not .
and 3re table it will check that in saved video table the course and the user is there or not if the course is there with same user it will unsave the course other wise it will return false .

Comment: One way is to call a single stored procedure and write your database related logic in it

Comment: ASP.NET isn't a database access technology. What you posted contains no database related code. No ADO.NET, no SQL, no EF Core or any other ORM. There's nothing that can be joined to anything else assuming there really is such a need. If you use an ORM like EF Core for example, loading related entities automatically generates JOINs from the relations and navigation properties, eg `context.Users.Select(u=>new {u.Name, Count=u.Playlists.Count()})` will generate the JOIN between Users and Playlists based on the `Playlists` navigation property

Answer (score 0):

you can write a StoredProcedure that has an Update statement. for filtering the result you can add a subquery in your WHERE statement.

```
UPDATE table
SET col = new_value
WHERE other_col IN (
SELECT other_col
FROM other_table    --You can add our joins here that checks user and...
WHERE conditional_col = 1
);
```